# GDB not breaking on SIGSEGV

Tags: linux, gdb, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to debug an application for an ARM processor from my x86 box.  I some followed instructions from someone that came before on getting a development environment setup.  I've got a version of `gdbserver` that has been cross-compiled for the ARM processor and appears to allow me to connect to it via my ARM-aware `gdb` on my box.

I'm expecting that when the process I've got `gdb` attached to crashes (from a SIGSEGV or similar) it will break so that I can check out the call stack.

Is that a poor assumption?  I'm new to the ARM world and cross-compiling things, is there possibly a good resource to get started on this stuff that I'm missing?

Comment: I recently ran across this blog post, it may prove useful in your situation. http://timetobleed.com/an-obscure-kernel-feature-to-get-more-info-about-dying-processes/

Answer (score 1):

So i assume that the gdb client is able to connect to gdbserver and you are able to put the break point on the running process right?

If all the above steps are successful then you should put the break point before the instruction which crashes, lets say if you dont know where is it crashing then i would say once the application is crashed, the core will be generated, take that core from the board. Then compile the source code again with debug option using -g option(if binaries are stripped) and do the offline ananlysis of core. something like below

gdb binary-name  core_file

Then once you get gdb prompt ,give below commands

gdb thread apply all bt

The above command will give you the complete backtrace of all the threads, remember that binaries should not be stripped and the proper path of all the source code and shared lib should be available.

you can switch between threads using below command on gdb prompt

gdb thread thread_number

If the core file is not getting generated on the board then try below command on board before executing the application

ulimit -c unlimited

Comment: I haven't tried to put in a breakpoint since I don't know where the process is crashing.  But I am able to connect to the `gdbserver`  and it appears as though it breaks upon attaching to the process and I can tell it to continue (so I assume I can put in my own software breakpoints, as well).  I'll try generating a core, currently it does not appear to make one, and get back to you.  Thanks!

Comment: You can also have a look in http://yusufonlinux.blogspot.com/2010/11/debugging-core-using-gdb.html

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the target system (the one which uses an ARM processor). Some embedded systems detect invalid memory accesses (e.g. dereferencing NULL) but react with unconditional, uncatchable system termination (I have done development on such a system). What kind of OS is the target system running ?

Comment: It's running a copy of the Linux kernel.